# What would I call this element?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, responsive-design, cards

I am trying to create a card that has a position absolute show more div option. I need it to not move any other elements and be responsive. I don't know how to do a search for it because I don't know what to call it. I attaching an image to show you what I mean. Any jsfiddle or codepen you can think of to help me with this would be great.[image]

Comment: This isn't a question about implementation, it's UI design pattern identification.

Comment: I call it a sliding div or a drawer. I don't know if there is a formal name to this element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what I've heard called a "drawer"

https://codepen.io/tag/drawer/